# Jquery UI slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

My Jquery slider is not working.

Here is my header code:

```
<head>
  <link href="/stylesheets/public.css?1316972296" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/tipTip.css?1263394346" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1316972671" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1316972675" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1312204886" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1316972551" type="text/javascript"></script>

              <script src="/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js?1314102048" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.tipTip.minified.js?1269274200" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="OALn13CELwr3umFrj2BVDeLzw8VhZ2Hmjm/+g2SrGRs="/>
    <script type="text/javascript">



                $(document).ready(function() {

                       $("#slider").slider({
    value: 100,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    step: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value == $(this).slider('option', 'max')) {
            $(ui.handle).html('Ubegrænset');
            $('#sliderValue').val('99999');
        } else {
            $(ui.handle).html(ui.value);
            $('#sliderValue').val(ui.value);
        }
    }
}).find('a').html($('#slider').slider('value'));

$('#sliderValue').val($('#slider').slider('value'));

                                $('.tip').tipTip(defaultPosition: "top");


                });

  </script> 
</head>
```

And in my page I have:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input id="sliderValue" />
```

Comment: What are you doing with `}).find('a').html($('#slider').slider('value'));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is syntactically incorrect:

```
$('.tip').tipTip(defaultPosition: "top");
```

You probably mean:

```
$('.tip').tipTip({ defaultPosition: "top" });
```

**Updated Sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/z3xV3/

Comment: There is no style added to slider. How to add a default theme?

Comment: @Railsbeginner: I would add a reference to a CSS theme on a CDN like Microsoft's: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryUI1816.ashx

Comment: I have added the reference, but the slider box is not adjusted to the text as your example

Comment: Could there be another error on your page? All I've done is paste the code from your OP and remove the line in question...

Comment: It is because my custom ui style gets overewrittin be hosted asp.net UI style

Comment: I downloaded the css theme and fixed the problem

Comment: @Railsbeginner: Awesome, glad you figured it out `:)`

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to add symbols or letters to the slider (not the value) ? :)

Comment: Looks like you could set the HTML of the handle to be whatever you want using `$(ui.handle).html('[html]');`. Not sure though.

Comment: $(ui.handle).html(ui.value + ' kr');